# text overflow: ellipsis inside flexible height div inside a div with a limited height

Tags: css, html

I have a div with a fixed size that contains a floated image, a title and a description. My issue is that the *desc* div does not stay within the boundaries of its parent when a lot of text is added to it. What I'd like to have is the text being cut off by an ellipsis when it reaches the bottom of the div. I have no control over the length of the content in the *name* and *desc* divs, so I can't impose a height on them. This seems very trivial, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsiah/z532E/9/)

For the sake of clarity, I mean that I want my result to look something like this:

```
{{name}}
{{desc.}} Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur adipisi
cing elit, sed do eiusmod tem
por incididunt ut labore et...
```

Edit: It turns out that this problem is a lot more involved than I expected. The issue doesn't have anything to do with div boundaries, but rather that multi-line ellipsis endings are not a trivial thing to accomplish.

**HTML**

```
<div id="data" class="clearfix">
 <img id="icon" src="{{imgurl}}">
 <div id="text">
    <div id="name">{{name}}</div>
    <div id="desc">{{desc}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#data {
 background-color:red;
 width:300px;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 23px 44px;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 color: #fff;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#icon {
 background-color: grey;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
#text {
 float: right;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#name {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}
#desc {
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.1em;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Live Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsiah/z532E/9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add whitespace and overflow when using ellipsis

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

I found this article documenting this... http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

and working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z532E/10/

Comment: I was aiming for multiple lines and ellipsis on the bottom one. This would be my second choice though.

Comment: Check out this http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

here is an interesting working example of what you want to do... i think http://codepen.io/romanrudenko/pen/bpeDF

Comment: That's clever! It also helped me figure out that what I'm asking for might not be as trivial as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great solution to your problem of multiple lines ellipsis found on codepen:
[Pure CSS multiline text with ellipsis](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqMQyP)

```
$font-size: 26px;
$line-height: 1.4;
$lines-to-show: 3;

h2 {
  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: $font-size*$line-height*$lines-to-show; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: $font-size;
  line-height: $line-height;
  -webkit-line-clamp: $lines-to-show;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

Comment: That is a great solution. Unfortunately it doesn't work in IE11